# If function - multiple conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I need the final output to be based on the values on the previous 4 columns,

My table has 6 columns (A-F). Values on Column B-E depends on value A. The final output result depends on the value based on the previous 4 columns B-E.

```
A = has some value
B - E : lookup value and dependent on A. Can be NA or value related to A
```

Conditions:

```
If B is not NA, then B value on F

If B is NA, check C,D,E

If C is not NA, Then C value on F

If C is NA, CHECK D,E

If D is not NA, then D value on F

If D is NA, Then Check E

If E is not NA, Then E value on F

If NA, then Value on F = NA
```

Tried If and Or but getting error.

> IF(B2<>"#N/A",B2,IF(C2<>"#N/A",C2,IF(D2<>"#N/A",D2,IF(E2<>"#N/A","REIN","NA"))))

Value to be REIN as E2 as value in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try entering this into cell F2

```
=IF(ISNA(B2)=FALSE,B2,IF(ISNA(C2)=FALSE,C2,IF(ISNA(D2)=FALSE,D2,IF(ISNA(E2)=FALSE,E2,"#N/A"))))
```

Comment: The catch here is C2,D2 and E2 has "#N/A" value but B2 has "NA" value. So the above formula "ISNA" captures on "#N/A" value, but for column B- NA it treats as a different value.

Comment: Not in front of a computer by try replacing “ISNA(B2)=FALSE” with “AND(ISNA(B2)=FALSE,B2<>”NA”)” and elsewhere where appropriate

Comment: Not working, still gets NA value even if Column E has value and Column B NA

Comment: ok - it turns out that it is fairly tricky.
Type this into F2:
    =IF(IF(OR(IFNA(B2,1)="NA",IFNA(B2,1)=1),"NA",B2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(C2,1)="NA",IFNA(C2,1)=1),"NA",C2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(D2,1)="NA",IFNA(D2,1)=1),"NA",D2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(E2,1)="NA",IFNA(E2,1)=1),"NA",E2)="NA","NA",E2),D2),C2),B2)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in F2:

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(NOT(ISNA(B2:E2)),),0))
```

It will return the first cell that is not an error.

[image]

Comment: The catch here is C2,D2 and E2 has "#N/A" value but B2 has "NA" value. So the above formula "ISNA" captures on "#N/A" value, but for column B- NA it treats as a different value.

Answer (score 0):

ok - it turns out that it is fairly tricky. Type this into F2: =IF(IF(OR(IFNA(B2,1)="NA",IFNA(B2,1)=1),"NA",B2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(C2,1)="NA",IFNA(C2,1)=1),"NA",C2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(D2,1)="NA",IFNA(D2,1)=1),"NA",D2)="NA",IF(IF(OR(IFNA(E2,1)="NA",IFNA(E2,1)=1),"NA",E2)="NA","NA",E2),D2),C2),B2)

I provided this answer on a comment above some time ago but wasn’t sure you saw it.